# Como fazer a soma desse número? Exemplo: “o número é 15 então seria 1+5 = resultado”

Tags: php

```
$numero = 15;
echo "Resultado: $numero";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combine  `array_sum` com `str_split` e poupe código - [exemplo ideone](https://ideone.com/zJdfV8)

array_sum — Calcula a soma dos elementos de um array

str_split — Converte uma string para um array. Sintaxe `str_split(string,tamanho)`
Se o parâmetro opcional `tamanho` for especificado, o array retornado será quebrado em pedaços com cada um estando com `tamanho` de comprimento, caso contrário cada pedaço terá um caractere de comprimento

```
$numero=123456789;

echo array_sum(str_split($numero));
```

> Com essa solução tem que escrever muito código

```
$num = str_split($numero, 1);
echo $num[0] + $num[1] + $num[2] + $num[3] +  $num[4] + .................;
```

> Neste caso seria melhor: [**ver no ideone**](https://ideone.com/MTdn1o)

```
$result=0;
$numero = 123456789;
$num = str_split($numero, 1);

for ($i=0;$i<count($num);$i++){
    $result += $num[$i];
}
```

Comment: Putz! Tinha esquecido do `array_sum`! Muito bom!

Comment: Muito bom tbm! Obrigado @leo Caracciolo

Answer (score 1):

Use o `str_split` para separar os dígitos e depois somá-los:

```
$numero = 15;
$num = str_split($numero, 1);
echo $num[0] + $num[1];
```

Comment: Muito bom @AndreiCoelho! vlww

Comment: @JsDev tranquilo... Tente deixa a pergunta um pouco mais clara. Isso evita negativações futuras!

Comment: @JsDev leia isto quando tiver tempo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Abraço!